# getting city information by sparql

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I tried with the following SPARQL query.

```
SELECT distinct ?city ?cityName ?country ?population ?knownfor WHERE {
 ?city rdf:type dbo:City .
?city rdfs:label ?cityName.
?city dbo:country ?country.
OPTIONAL{
?city dbp:population ?population.
?city dbo:knownFor ?knownfor.
}

  FILTER (lang(?cityName) = 'en')
} ORDER BY ?city
```

But, the problem is -

1. Not every city has `dbp:population` predicate but some city has `dbp:populationTotal`. So, for some cities we can get the population by this  but  when i write in the optional section of the query -

   ```
   OPTIONAL{
       ?city dbp:population ?population .
       ?city dbp:populationTotal ?populationTotal
   }
   ```

the both section become blank. Same goes for `dbo:knownFor` predicate (not every city have `knownFor` predicate).

2. How can I specify in the query that i want only the European city? I can not find any predicate which specify the continent of the city

Answer (score 1):

First thing to know is that DBpedia data is a moving target, just like the Wikipedia data from which it is derived.  Updates to Wikipedia will eventually be part of DBpedia.  More quickly, they'll be part of [DBpedia-live](http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql).

The issue with values for neither `OPTIONAL` predicate showing up when you include both predicates appears to be a bug in the Virtuoso version currently hosting DBpedia.  I encourage you to check [whether it's been reported yet](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/), report it yourself if not, and monitor the issue.

As to limiting the continent of the cities you get back -- it's usually easiest to check an entity of (or near) the sort you want, to find a relevant attribute/predicate/property.  For instance, [Aachen-Mitte](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Aachen-Mitte) has a `dbo:country` of [Germany](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Germany), which has a number of `rdf:type`s including `yago:EuropeanCountries` -- which might be what you want, but might not yet have been applied to all such.  You'll need to add a triple to your pattern like --

```
?country  a  yago:EuropeanCountries
```

### Edit To Add

The `OPTIONAL { ... }` clause returns results for the entire pattern enclosed within the braces.  So --

```
OPTIONAL
  {
    ?city dbp:population ?population .
    ?city dbo:knownFor   ?knownfor   .
  }
```

-- will only return values for *either* predicate when that `?city` has values for *both* predicates.

If you want to get *every* value for *either* predicate, you need to split that clause into two --

```
OPTIONAL
  {
    ?city dbp:population ?population .
  }
OPTIONAL
  {
    ?city dbo:knownFor   ?knownfor   .
  }
```

It's easy to get both `dbp:population` *and* `dbp:populationTotal`, with both `OPTIONAL` (and adding `?populationTotal` to your `SELECT` list) --

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?city
                ?cityName
                ?country 
                ?population
                ?populationTotal
                ?knownfor
...
OPTIONAL
  {
    ?city dbp:population      ?population      .
  }
OPTIONAL
  {
    ?city dbp:populationTotal ?populationTotal .
  }
OPTIONAL
  {
    ?city dbo:knownFor        ?knownfor        .
  }
```

If you only want *one* of the population values, and especially if you have a preference of one predicate over the other, the construction gets more complex (and should be a new question).

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. Ya, all city of Europe does not have the yago:EuropeanCountries predicate and that's why those cities are missing. But my question is, why that predicate is missing?

Comment: The predicate is missing from DBpedia, because the categorization has not been made in Wikipedia. Most errors in DBpedia data must be corrected by correcting the Wikipedia content from which the DBpedia data gets extracted.  Go edit Wikipedia, wait a few hours or days, and then run your query against DBpedia-live (which updates from the Wikipedia firehose); or wait 3–9 months for the next bulk extraction and run your query against DBpedia.